# In what steps does microbenchmark execute a code given?

Tags: r, microbenchmark

Here what I wanted to do. I have 2 different ways of multiplying matrices. So I want to find which way is better. I used microbenchmark package and I called each functions to check their performing time. Since my matrices are too large, I want to get the answering matrix, then remove it, and clear the garbage. So I wrote following code. By doing this 100 times, I want to find which method creates the answering matrix faster.

```
set.seed(100)    
library(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)

matrix.multiply.method1 <- function(cl, A, B){
  ans <- clusterApply(cl, lapply(splitIndices(nrow(A), length(cl)), function(ii) A[ii,,drop=FALSE]), get("%*%"), B)
  do.call(rbind, ans)
}

matrix.multiply.method2 <- function(A,B){
  return (A%*%B)
}

nr <- 5000
A <- matrix(round(rnorm(nr^2),1),nr=nr)
B <- matrix(round(runif(nr^2),1),nr=nr)

timing <- microbenchmark(
    x <- matrix.multiply.method1(A,B),
    remove (x),
    gc(),
    y <- matrix.multiply.method2(A,B),
    remove(y),
    gc()
)

stopCluster(cl)
timing
```

I want to know how does microbenchmark execute these steps 100 times? Does microbenchmark execute one line 100 times, and then go to the 2nd line? Or does it execute all the lines one time and again and again for the 100th time?

I wanted to know that because when I run this code, it gives me a warning saying it cannot remove objects 'x' and 'y'. So I thought the way that microbenchmark execute the code is the reason for that.

Comment: @Hack-R done. Sorry for the Bad writing.

Comment: Thanks, no worries. We just need the data objects now for reproducibility. Can you `dput()` or create them in your question?

Comment: You should check out the documentation for [microbenchmark](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/microbenchmark.pdf). There is no need to remove your objects and there is no need for the `<-` assignment operator. Instead, use `x = ...` and `y = ...`

Comment: Additionally, there is no worry for the order in which you type the methods for comparison as the function randomly test each method.  You also don't have to worry about overhead as most of the code is written in `C` and there is a `warm-up` phase to determine the time it takes to call each function.  All in all, it's super awesome!

Comment: @Hack-R pasted the complete coding I used.

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks. I didn't know that function randomly test each method. So I guess that is the reason why it says it cannot find the object to remove.

Comment: @Hansy, no problem. For your situation, all you need at the end is `timing <- microbenchmark(x = matrix.multiply.method1(A,B), y = matrix.multiply.method2(A,B))`

Comment: It cleans up for you, but if you were going to by hand, you'd have to put both commands in one parameter (i.e. between commas). If that requires multiple lines, combine with `;` or wrap multiline code in `{...}`.